# Как закодировать password в md5?

Tags: android, md5

Что то у меня не выходит закодировать одну переменную, подскажите как это сделать.

```
    public class LoginPage extends Activity {
        public static final String Login = "login";
        public static final String Password = "password";
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.efrgtaw);
        inal EditText loginIn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        final EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        Button butlogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

            butlogin.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Please wait, connecting to server.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    try {
        String loginValue = URLEncoder.encode(loginIn.getText().toString(), "UTF-8");
        String passwordStr = URLEncoder.encode(password.getText().toString(), "UTF-8");
        HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        String URL = "http://" + accountValue + ".megaplan.ru/BumsCommonApiV01/User/authorize.api/"+ loginValue + passwordStr + "";
        Log.i("httpget", URL);
    try {
        String SetServerString = "";
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(URL);
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        SetServerString = Client.execute(httpget,responseHandler);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
} finally {}
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {}}});}}
```

Хочу password передать в виде md5. Именно password, login не трогать.

Такой вариант не захотел работать:

```
MessageDigest digest = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
digest.update(Password.getBytes());
byte messageDigest[] = digest.digest();
StringBuffer MD5Hash = new StringBuffer();
for (int i = 0; i < messageDigest.length; i++){
String h = Integer.toHexString(0xFF & messageDigest[i]);
while (h.length() < 2)
h = "0" + h;
MD5Hash.append(h);}
```

Comment: > Такой вариант не захотел работать

Однако он вполне верен. И вообще, поясните, что значит "не захотел работать"?

Comment: не кодирует мой пароль, и передается в сервер чистым видом (
Может этот кусок кода я не туда сую? ((

Comment: В вышеприведённом коде я не вижу хеширования, как получили `passwordStr` из `EditText`, так и отправляете, в чистом виде.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку ))) Я не заметила как то )))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка была в том, что я неверно передавала данные. После исправления, пароль был закодирован и передан как положено.